# While loop inside a for loop concatening

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop

when I execute this code it spits out a new row inside the table but it includes the previous iteration along with the newest one.  I want all "As" to be in the first  row in the main table.  And then I want all "Bs" to be in the second , etc, etc.  Then for A0, A1, and A2, I want them to be in their own table within the first row, same for B0, B1 in the second row, etc, etc

```html
<head>
  <style>
  table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  }
  </style>
</head>

<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>gerp gerp</td>
    <td>
      <table id="0"></table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>gerp gerp</td>
    <td>
      <table id="1"></table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>gerp gerp</td>
    <td>
      <table id="2"></table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>gerp gerp</td>
    <td>
      <table id="3"></table>
    </td>
  </tr>


</table>

<script>
  var array = [
    ["A0---", "A1----", "A2---"],
    ["B0----", "B1---"],
    ["C0---", "C1---"],
    ["D0---", "D1---"]
  ];

  var text = ""
  console.log(array.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

    var j = 0;
    console.log(array[i].length);
    while (j < array[i].length) {
      text += "<tr><td>" + array[i][j] + "</td></tr>";
      j++;
    }

    document.getElementById(i).innerHTML = text;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the `text` variable to the empty string *inside* the first loop instead:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  let text = '';
```

But note that you can make your code more functional, shorter, and easier to read by using array methods like `.map` and `forEach` rather than using `for`, `while`, and manual iteration (better not to have to keep track of indicies):

```
array.forEach((subArr, i) => {
  const text = subArr.map(item => "<tr><td>" + item + "</td></tr>");
  document.getElementById(i).innerHTML = text.join('');
});
```

```js
var array = [
  ["A0---", "A1----", "A2---"],
  ["B0----", "B1---"],
  ["C0---", "C1---"],
  ["D0---", "D1---"]
];

array.forEach((subArr, i) => {
  const text = subArr.map(item => "<tr><td>" + item + "</td></tr>");
  document.getElementById(i).innerHTML = text.join('');
});
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>gerp gerp</td>
    <td>
      <table id="0"></table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>gerp gerp</td>
    <td>
      <table id="1"></table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>gerp gerp</td>
    <td>
      <table id="2"></table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>gerp gerp</td>
    <td>
      <table id="3"></table>
    </td>
  </tr>


</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare this variable `var text = "";` inside of the `for-loop`

```js
var array = [  ["A0---", "A1----", "A2---"],  ["B0----", "B1---"],  ["C0---", "C1---"],  ["D0---", "D1---"]];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var text = "";
  var j = 0;
  while (j < array[i].length) {
    text += "<tr><td>" + array[i][j] + "</td></tr>";
    j++;
  }

  document.getElementById(i).innerHTML = text;
}
```

```css
table,th,td {  border: 1px solid black;}
```

```html
<table id="table">  <tr>    <td>gerp gerp</td>    <td>      <table id="0"></table>    </td>  </tr>  <tr>    <td>gerp gerp</td>    <td>      <table id="1"></table>    </td>  </tr>  <tr>    <td>gerp gerp</td>    <td>      <table id="2"></table>    </td>  </tr>  <tr>    <td>gerp gerp</td>    <td>      <table id="3"></table>    </td>  </tr></table>
```